# filter column and then replace character if condition is met in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns (nights,rate).  In the nights column where value equals '2', if rate column value does not contain a pipe('|'), replace period ('.') with a pipe ('|').

I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

---

5-23-23
I have adjusted the dataframe on lines 3 & 5 when you run this.  It seems the replace all statement changes (all periods to pipe). I wonder if possible to ask the question " if nights(column) = 2 & rate(column) does NOT contain a pipe('|') then replace period with pipe, else leave alone. Explanation: Some of the amounts in the rate column are legit amounts as shown in lines 3 & 5. These are already separated by pipes as they should be.  Sorry Nick, I got to excited about this fix I didn't see the complete report.  Thank you for helping me.

---

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[2, '10.10'], [3, '15|15'], [2, '14.14'],[4,'20|20.34|20|20.3'],[2,'30.30'],[3,'121.23|121.23|121.23']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nights', 'rate'])

#df2 is what I'd like to see
data2 = [[2, '10|10'], [3, '15|15'], [2, '14|14'],[4,'20|20.34|20|20.3'],[2,'30|30'],[3,'121.23|121.23|121.23']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['nights', 'rate'])


#df.loc[df['nights'] == 2, 'rate'].str.replace('\.','\|')  #not Working

#df.loc[(df['nights'] == 2) & (~df['rate'].str.contains('\|').str.replace('\.','\|') #Not working

# test = df['rate'].str.contains('\|') #works to identify pipe or not
# print(test)

print(df)
print('\n')
print(df2)
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['nights'] == 2, 'rate'] = df.loc[df['nights'] == 2, 'rate'].str.replace('.','|')` works for me.

Comment: Thank you Nick.  Works great.  I didn't know you could link  loc(s) together like this...

Comment: No worries - glad it was helpful

Comment: df.loc[(df['nights'] == 2) & (~df['rate'].str.contains('\|')), 'rate'] = df.loc[(df['nights'] == 2) & (~df['rate'].str.contains('\|')), 'rate'].str.replace('.', '|')

Comment: Note that `df['rate'] = df['rate'].str.replace('.', '|', regex=False)` is likely the most explicit. It doesn't hurt to process the rows that already have the correct separator.

Comment: @mozway only issue with that is that it would replace `.` for `nights` values other than `2` (which admittedly doesn't occur in the sample data, but might IRL)

Comment: @Nick I know but I have a feeling this is ultimately what is needed (XY problem?). I wish all questions would have the correct counterexamples. If there can be cases with a `.` that should remained unchanged, this should be explicited ;)

Comment: @mozway couldn't agree with you more!

Comment: Nick, again thankyou and the others for helping me with this.  I got excited with your answer I failed to see the changing of the legit rate amounts with periods & already existing pipes.  I have adjusted the main script & question to show you.  Akash Kumar (below) actually nailed it.  I feel bad for not giving you guys a good example to work with.  The question was correct.  Again Thank you for your time spent on this.

Comment: @Boomer no worries at all. I would say that my code does still work for your edited sample data, but if there was an entry `(2, '14.3|15.5')` or similar it wouldn't and that is where Akash's answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the desired output :

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[2, '10.10'], [3, '15|15'], [2, '14.14'], [4, '20|20|20|20'], [2, '30.30']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nights', 'rate'])

df.loc[(df['nights'] == 2) & (~df['rate'].str.contains('\|')), 'rate'] = df.loc[(df['nights'] == 2) & (~df['rate'].str.contains('\|')), 'rate'].str.replace('.', '|')

print(df)
```

Then the output will be:

```
   nights       rate
0       2      10|10
1       3      15|15
2       2      14|14
3       4  20|20|20|20
4       2      30|30
```

Comment: Akash Kumar.  Thank you very much with this.  I have tested your script with the report and it's working great.  I appreciate your time!!!